# Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to check an input='checkbox' in a table called (#gridModalListeDossiers) when its checked in another table (#gridDossiers) , however I'm getting this error and I dont understand it :

[image: Error : Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded]

Here is my method :

```
$('#gridDossiers').on('check.bs.table', lang.hitch( this, function (row , $element) {
            var dataTable = $('#gridDossiers').bootstrapTable('getData')
            $.each(dataTable, function (i, rowData) {
                if (rowData.select_dossier === true) {
                    $('#gridModalListeDossiers').bootstrapTable('check', i)
                }
            }) 
        }))
```

Anyone knows how to deal with this error?

Comment: Which line of your code is causing this error?

Comment: Maybe drop the lang.hitch? Looks like some DOJO thingy

Comment: last line which causes the error : `$('#gridModalListeDossiers').bootstrapTable('check', i)`

Comment: Also update to jQuery 3.6.2 and bootstrap-5 or 6

Comment: Looks like you are nesting boostrapTables

Comment: Also ` $('#gridModalListeDossiers')` is a unique ID so you do this for each dataTable ? If there is only ONE gridDossiers and only ONE gridModalListeDossiers, as one would expect then don't loop

Answer (score 0):

`$('#gridModalListeDossiers')` is a unique ID so you do this for each dataTable ? If there is only ONE gridDossiers and only ONE gridModalListeDossiers, as one would expect then don't loop

Try something like this

```
$('#gridDossiers').on('check.bs.table', function() {
  const dataTable = $(this).bootstrapTable('getData')
  if (dataTable.select_dossier) {
    $('#gridModalListeDossiers').bootstrapTable('check', true)
  }
})
```

Comment: $('#gridModalListeDossiers') is the Id of my table that contains data (multiple rows) and same of $('#gridDossiers') is another table (same as #gridModalListeDossiers) so I absolutely need to loop

Comment: you cannot have multiple identical IDs